# Soft question about introducing measure in topological space

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, soft-question

I've heard about possibility to introduce measure to some topological spaces, without knowing the nature of its elements. Is it true? I doubt, if this is true for arbitrary topological space (unless I'm satisfied with some trivial measures like counting one or constant-zero-measure), however if it is possible in some cases, then are there any books or papers about it?

I've read in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/43601/measure-on-topological-spaces) that it was an old question, and there are some useful remarks here... though I'm more interested in reading a bit more about it, especially if I'd like to quote some scientific lectures in my work.

If anyone could provide me with some resources on that topic - I'd be grateful.

Comment: This may be of interest, for the special case where the topology is given by a metric. [induced measure](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1194313/a-rigorous-meaning-of-induced-measure)

Comment: Well, unfortunately I'm working mostly on non-metrizable spaces, but yes, this might be helpful as well. Anything else would be nice.

Comment: Well, here is what I would think of as the basic consideration:

Whenever we are given a topology, there is a collection of open sets. These give rise to a borel $\sigma$-algebra generated by open sets. This has the benefit that:

1. Closed and open sets are in your $\sigma$-algebra
2. The continuous functions are all measurable.

I'm certainly no expert, but after a quick google search, it appears that this construction is quite common on probability theory.

Comment: The construction of measures on locally compact Hausdorff spaces is a pretty standard topic in real analysis and measure theory, I think. For instance, I know that Royden's and Folland's real analysis textbooks cover this. [This book](https://smile.amazon.com/Topological-Riesz-Spaces-Measure-Theory/dp/0521090318/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1491228944&sr=8-1&keywords=fremlin+measure+topological) by Fremlin on this topic has been recommended to me as well. Also, you could just look at wikipedia on [Radon measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon_measure).

Comment: See "Haar Measure" (note the spelling) in Wikipedia. It is a measure on a locally compact, Hausdorff topological group. The space $\mathbb R^n $ ($1\leq n<\infty$) where the group operation is vector addition, is such a group

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Volume 4 of Measure Theory, by Fremlin is a great resource. The TeX sources can be downloaded and compiled, or you could buy them as well. 
All books are "encyclopaedic" (quite thorough) and cover a lot of standard and more obscure results. 
One part of volume 4 is about the construction of a nice measure on certain types of spaces (like on locally compact Hausdorff spaces, using the dual of $C(X)$ and other functional analysis techniques...) and also on the interplay between a measure and topology (often minimally all open sets should be measurable, so we have Borel measures), for some spaces such measures sometimes we get so-called regularity in different forms (inner / outer etc.). You should check them out..