# Intuition for definition of Radon Measure

Tags: measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory

According to the definition of the book "Measure Theory and fine properties of functions." -Evans Gariapery a measure u is said of Radon if they are worth the properties described in the attached image.

According to the Wiki the motivation for this definition is to find a way to measure sets of a topological space so that this way of measuring is compatible with the topology of space.

In simple terms, what precisely would "find a measure that is compatible with the topology?" Answering this question gives the intuition behind Radon's definition of measurement?

[image]

Comment: I can't figure out what you're asking.

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/43601/measure-on-topological-spaces/51109) asks a similar question. The accepted answer may be helpful.